# How to create right API URLs for getting data

Tags: rest, api, url

I'm creating a simple API which works with geographical data.

Some URLs look very simple like:

```
GET /towns/{id}
```

or

```
GET /towns
```

Now I want to get a town by alias, should I use this kind of URL?

```
GET /towns/alias/{alias}
```

What if I also want to get a list of towns located near certain town?

```
GET /towns/closest/{id}/radius/{radius}
```

I understand that my URLs can be any I want. What is a canonical way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that my URLs can be any I want. What is a canonical way to do it?

There isn't really a "canonical way" to design URLs, any more than there is a canonical way to name variables -- there are only local spelling conventions.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) distinguishes between hierarchical and non-hierarchical data:

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any)

The effect of using hierarchical data is that you can take advantage of dot-segments to compute one URI from another.

For example

```
/town/alias/{alias}
/alias/{alias}
```

Both of these spellings are "fine", but `/town/alias` gives us the option of using dot segments to specify an identifier under `/town`

```
/town/alias/abc + ../123
  => /town/alias/../123 
  => /town/123
```

That can be handy when it allows you to re-use a representation for multiple resources in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can possible through the URL routing.You can send any number of parameter through url.

Can you please confirm the technology you used?